# [bootstrap]button not centered in narrow screen using center-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/c5befo3h/2/

The whole discussion is based on above jsfiddle.

1. I don't understand why the button is shifted left instead of center with only standard `btn btn-default` class.
   https://jsfiddle.net/c5befo3h/
2. I add `center-block` to center the button. Is it a recommended way? If so, as i narrowing the screen, the button starts to be not centered.
   [image: reach screen edge]

   (1)I found out that's because of `padding`.
   (2)And it overflows.
   [image: exceed screen]
   How to avoid (1),(2)?
3. My desired outcome is if the screen is wide enough, button is horizontal and vertical align in all situation.
   For narrow screen, it drops to next line and horizontal and vertical aligned.
   How to archive the vertical align according parent height.
   Sorry to ask a different question here, but I have gone through similar questions on stackoverflow and still don't have solution.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the outcome you desire?

I've changed the column sizes to point `md` screens and separate how it looks like on `xs` screens.

For the button alignment, padding should work.

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-5 form-group'>
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-5 form-group'>
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-2'>
      <button class="btn btn-default center-block">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it seems I have to use different size in bootstrap. The reason why I only used xs is I read the doc that smaller screen rule can be applied to larger ones. So i only apply xs to let it float automatically. Feel free to add vertical alignment for that button~

Comment: And do you know why the button is not centered in xs?

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting problem. I do not know why this is happening but I was able to resolve it:

If you give the "col-md-2" another class and give that class a padding of zero it resolves the issue.

```
.padding-right-col-2 {
padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's kinda interesting that if apply lg/md (larger screen), then it'd be ok and I assume it'd be centered in normal situation.
I don't want to cancel the padding in this way so not to affect similar class.
If really have to, maybe I'd add id for that element and cancel the padding but it's ugly and seems there'd be another solution

Answer (score 0):

As for vertical alignment, look through logs of hacks to bootstrap.
And best solution I provide is using flexbox.

NOTICE: as it not work for xs, apply only to screen size larger than xs

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.vertical-align > div {
margin: auto;
}
}
```

updated version:
https://jsfiddle.net/c5befo3h/3/